# How can I call a set of AWS Step Functions in a loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have created a set of Step Functions that take about *15 minutes* to run start to finish.

I would like to run these in a synchronous loop, and pass values from an array. The values are just a sequence of 7 dates.

I think just writing a lambda to call and wait for each run to end, before calling the next loop would be wasteful, since each loop takes 15 minutes..

Is there a way to create a 'parent' step function to run this loop, or some other logical way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MAP task and provide your input as array.
Then MAP Task will run on all those 7 elements in your array in your case.
Refer link below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html

Comment: As an aside, I wanted to send a dynamically created array to the MAP task. The way to do that is a previous step function that creates the array through a lambda, and passes that to the MAP task, which nests other step functions.

Comment: Yup.. so first tasks output will be passed to Map task and it can iterate over that